# Unable to access jarfile from a script on MAC

Tags: java, linux, macos, executable-jar

I'm trying to write a script that runs a .jar file.
The following command works from terminal (from the .jar file folder):

```
java -jar "./myjavatest.jar"
```

When I put this line in a file and run it from the same folder (using terminal or double-click in finder), I get "Unable to access jarfile ./myjavatest.jar".

I figured out that when I double click a file, it actually runs from the user home directory.
Is it possible to run it from the folder that the file is located at?

Comment: you could cd to the directory where the .jar is located. But then you could simply use the complete path instead of the relative one, too.

Comment: Place your jar file in the same folder as your script and just use java -jar myjavatest.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I figured out that when I double click a file, it actually runs from the user home directory. Is it possible to run it from the folder that the file is located at?

Yes there is:

```
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
DIR="$( dirname "$SOURCE" )"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]
do 
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE"  )" && pwd )"
done
DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

cd "$DIR"

java -jar myjavatest.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing permisions to the file and directory with `chmod 755 javatest.jar` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Nothing.
When I do "ls" in the script file, I saw that it runs from the user home folder and not the script folder. This is why the jar file can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem trying execute a .sh file with this content:
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -jar -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 mainRPV.jar

the problem was that for some reason the file format was changed to DOS instead of UNIX, probably because it has been edited and saved in windows.
its related to line endings

try open the file with vim and run this command :set ff=unix

regards!